# Inputting text in search box and then selecting from Auto Complete with Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium, autocomplete

I am trying to input some text in a search box using selenium and python. The code is below. It runs perfectly well up until the point if selecting the 'premier league' option. Although when this text is entered it comes up in the box as a pre-defined option I am unable to select and click it as I want...If you are navigating the webpage you can click on the 'premier league' option and it loads a new page. I don't seem to be able to replicate this

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchAttributeException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/scores-fixtures")


try:
    elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('sp-c-date-picker-timeline__item')
except:
    print('Was not able to find an element with that name.')

time.sleep(5)
elem.click()


try:
    elem2=browser.find_element_by_class_name('sp-c-search__input')
except:
    print('Not able to find an element with that name')

time.sleep(3)

elem2.send_keys('premier league')
time.sleep(2)

#searching for the text works but i can't select it

#elem2.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
#time.sleep(2)
#elem2.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
#time.sleep(2)
#elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#elem2.submit()

elem2.select_by_visible_text('Premier League')
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have tried to identify the `Search Box` through `classname` identifies as follows :

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_class_name('sp-c-date-picker-timeline__item')
#and
elem2=browser.find_element_by_class_name('sp-c-search__input')
```

These locators doesn't identifies the `Search Box` uniquely.

To `input some text in a search box` you have to identify the `Search Box` with placeholder set to `Enter a team or competition` through a unique `CSS` or `XPATH` as follows :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='sp-c-search__input']").send_keys("premier league")
```

Finally, to `click()` on the option with text as **`Premier League`** you can use the following code block :

```
suggestions = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='sp-c-search__input']//following::div[@id='search-results']//ul/li/a/mark"))
for suggestion in suggestions :
    if suggestion.get_attribute("innerHTML").contains("Premier League") :
        suggestion.click()
```

---

### Update

As you are seeing the error as :

```
NameError: name 'By' is not defined
```

Ensure that you have added all the following imports :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. I get the following error. Does it run for you?
suggestions = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='sp-c-search__input']//following::div[@id='search-results']//ul/li/a/mark")))
NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: Updated my Answer. Let me know the status.