# How to get the text from the auto suggestion of the auto complete text box?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, browser-automation

[image]My requirement is **I want to select the particular name from the auto-suggestion in the autocomplete text box**.

So here I only know how to get the name by using the mouse down to achieve this But I know it's not a good solution to get that because we don't give the guarantee to the auto-suggestion is same as all the time in the browser.

**So if anyone knows how to get the auto-suggested text names for the auto-complete text box in Selenium Web Driver using Junit (Here I am using the Junit in Selenium WebDriver to develop the automation test script).**

My code:

```
driver.findElement("//input[@id='phSearchInput']").SendKeys(KEYS.ARROW_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement("//input[@id='phSearchInput']").SendKeys(KEYS.ARROW_DOWN);
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement("//input[@id='phSearchInput']").SendKeys(KEYS.ENTER);
```

> Here the above code is only working for my correct option is shows as
>   the second option of the auto-suggested texts.

So that's why I need how to get the text names in the auto-suggestion for the autocomplete text box.

**Please the give the solutions as the JUnit Form to my question because I am using the JUnit to develop the automation test script.**

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inputting text in search box and then selecting from Auto Complete with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011101/inputting-text-in-search-box-and-then-selecting-from-auto-complete-with-selenium/48011999#48011999)

Comment: @DebanjanB hi, I am asking the solutions in JUnit. but you give the answer in python. I am struggling to get that answer sir

Comment: Can you inspect on any auto-suggestion item? If so put the HTML code of whole auto-suggestion list at here,  so that we can tell you how to find wanted auto-suggestion item.  It's better you can take a screenshot includes looks-like and HTML code  of auto-suggestion  in one picture.

Comment: Could you paste the HTML code in your question?

Comment: @Anand  Now I add the snapshot which has the suggested items and HTML code for that autocomplete checkbox also I indicated with the square.

Comment: @yong, Now I add the snapshot which has the suggested items and HTML code for that autocomplete checkbox also I indicated with the square

Comment: Ok, thanks. Could you expand the <a>? I need to know where the text Kringle Lam DEV3 is. This way I can generate an xpath for you to click on that element. Once you have a working XPath (in the browser dev tools, click Console at the top, typ $x("Xpath here") and check if it shows) you can simply click on it.

Comment: Hoping to solve your issue here, try xpath: //*[contains(text(), 'Kringle Lam DEV3 ID User')]

Comment: @Anand thanks for the reply. My question is How I get the text as my screenshot having the two suggested link. like "Directly saying How I get the auto-suggested options names like in the picture Kringle LAM DEV3 and Kringle Lam DEV3 ID User as a form of text format.

Comment: Ah got it! In that case you can use the findelements functionality. So you can say: List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//a[@class='autoCompleteRowLink']"); And then for each list item you can use getText to get the exact text. Then you can assert it with the expected values.

Comment: @Anand, Thanks for your help. please post this as an answer for I accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you can use the findelements functionality. So you can say:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(by.xpath("//a[@class='autoCompleteRowLin‌​k']");
```

And then for 
each list item you can use getText to get the exact text. Then you can assert it with the expected values

Answer (score 1):

The auto-suggest box is HTML like anything else on the page. Create a locator that finds the auto-suggest panel and then parse the contents. Once you figure out the structure, you can get the text that you need and then assert that it is correct.

I can't see the full HTML from your screenshot but you can see that the list is contained in an HTML UL. The UL is the container and each LI is a list item in the dropdown. You can use that info to do something like

```
ul.autoCompleteGroup > li
```

to get all the list items. I can't see what's inside of there but at some point you should be able to use `.getText()` to get the auto suggest items. From there you just compare what you pulled off the list to what you are expecting with an Assert.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
public void selectAutoCompleteItem(String itemText) {
    String xpathPattern = "//div[@id='phSearchInput_autoCompleteBoxId']" +
                          "//ul/li/a[.='%s')]";

    String xpathExp = String.format(xpathPattern, itemText);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExp)).click();
}
```